# How to put number in nested ProgressBar Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-progressbar

I wanted to create nested `ProgressBar` like below image. I have created the nested `Progress Bar` but I am not able to put the **number** value on every `Progress Bar`.

Please help how to create this.

[image: nested ProgressBar]

**XML File:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:CustomFontName="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="b.Activity.HomePageActivity">

<b.customFonts.CustomFontTextView
    CustomFontName:fontName="@string/gotham_bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/clock_icon"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/periodic_reports" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape_green"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="56"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_green1" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape_green"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="96"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_green2" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape_green"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="56"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_green3" />

    <b.customFonts.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/progressBarText"
        CustomFontName:fontName="@string/gotham_book"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Last 30 days Reports"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Thanks for help.**